# load corbertura file using intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, cobertura

I hava a cobertura.xml, Is it possible load this file usin intellij to see the comberture?.

I checked this file on jenkins and works fine.

The cobertura is for javascript.

I am using intellij idea 15 comunity edition.